# Linux shared library versioning for backwards compatibility using libtool

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, libtool

I maintain a shared library that uses `libtool`, runs (mostly) on Linux and spits out the following files.

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    18 jun 10 16:12 libxxx.so -> libxxx.so.0.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    18 jun 10 16:12 libxxx.so.0 -> libxxx.so.0.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  760K jun 10 16:12 libxxx.so.0.0.1
```

libtool `version-info` is currently `0:1:0`

I want to add functionality to the library's API/ABI, not remove or modify any existing API/ABI so that:

- I produce a library that can still be used by binaries built against the older versions of the library. So the new library acts as a drop-in replacement, no rebuilding of old binaries is needed.
- Binaries built against the new library and using the new API/ABI fail at the loading stage when the library containing the new API is not found.

How can I achieve this with libtool?

I tried setting version-info to 1:0:1 as suggested [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Updating-version-info.html#Updating-version-info)

> Programs using the previous version may use the new version as drop-in replacement, but programs using the new version may use APIs not present in the previous one. In other words, a program linking against the new version may fail with “unresolved symbols” if linking against the old version at runtime: set revision to 0, bump current and age.

This results in the following files:

```
rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    18 jun 10 16:24 libxxx.so -> libxxx.so.0.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    18 jun 10 16:24 libxxx.so.0 -> libxxx.so.0.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  760K jun 10 16:24 libxxx.so.0.1.0
```

However, binaries built against the new library will load and will then fail during runtime with an `undefined symbol` error if at runtime they enter a codepath that includes one of the new symbols not present in the old library.

I can increase the `SONAME` to `libxxx.so.1` but then I break the binaries built against the older version, while the new version is still compatible.

Comment: "binaries compiled against the new library will fail at runtime with an undefined symbol error if at runtime they encounter the old library."  -- isn't that _exactly_ what you asked for?

Comment: No, they crash when they encounter the symbol, I want them to fail when they are loaded.

Comment: They don['t crash, they fail (at loading stage). I think you need to clarify _exactly_ what you want to happen instead.

Comment: Is it more clear now @EmployedRussian?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand how. You are having a failure at runtime (when a new symbol is called), and you want a failure at load time instead?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, binaries built against the new library will load and will then fail during runtime with an undefined symbol error if at runtime they enter a codepath that includes one of the new symbols not present in the old library.

TL;DR: I don't think there is a solution that will achieve desired result *right now* (unless you are already using versioned symbols), but you can make it a bit better now, and can fix it *completely* for the next time.

---

This is a problem that is that solved by the [GNU symbol version extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SymbolVersioning).

It's probably best to have an example. Initial setup:

```
// foo_v1.c
int foo() { return 42; }

// main_v1.c
int main() { return foo(); }

gcc -fPIC -shared -o foo.so foo_v1.c
gcc -w main_v1.c ./foo.so -o main_v1

./main_v1; echo $?
42
```

Now let's modify `foo.c` so it's a drop-in replacement, but has new function:

```
mv foo.so foo.so.v1

// foo_v2.c
int foo() { return 42; }
int bar() { return 24; }

gcc -fPIC -shared -o foo.so foo_v2.c

./main_v1; echo $?
42
```

Everything still works (as expected). Now let's build `main_v2` which requires new function.

```
// main_v2.c
int main() { return foo() - bar(); }

gcc -w main_v2.c ./foo.so -o main_v2

./main_v2; echo $?
18
```

Everything still works. And now we break things:

```
mv foo.so foo.so.v2
cp foo.so.v1 foo.so
./main_v1; echo $?
42
./main_v2
./main_v2: symbol lookup error: ./main_v2: undefined symbol: bar
```

Voila: we have a failure at runtime, instead of (desired) failure at load time. (This isn't actually visible in the above output, but can trivially verified by adding e.g. `printf` in `main`.)

**Solution:**
Let's give `foo.so` a version script:

```
// foo.lds
FOO_v2 {
  global: bar;
};

gcc -fPIC -shared -o foo.so foo_v2.c -Wl,--version-script=foo.lds
gcc -w main_v2.c ./foo.so -o main_v2a

./main_v1; echo $?
42
./main_v2a; echo $?
18
```

As we can see, everything still works with the new version of the library.

But what happens when we run the new `main_v2a` against old `foo.so`?

```
mv foo.so foo.so.v2
cp foo.so.v1 foo.so
./main_v2

./main_v2a: ./foo.so: no version information available (required by ./main_v2a)
./main_v2a: symbol lookup error: ./main_v2a: undefined symbol: bar, version FOO_v2
```

This is little bit better: the failure is *still* happening at runtime, but the loader does mention `FOO_v2`, providing a hint that this is caused by some kind of "version too old" problem.

The reason the loader doesn't fail at load time is that the (old) `foo.so` has no version info whatsoever.

If you now repeat this process, creating `FOO_v3` with a new function, and try to run `main_v3` against the `foo.so.v2` version of the library, you would get a failure at load time:

```
// foo_v3.c
int foo() { return 42; }
int bar() { return 24; }
int baz() { return 12; }

// foo_v3.lds
FOO_v2 {
  global: bar;
};
FOO_v3 {
  global: baz;
} FOO_v2;

// main_v3.c
int main() { return foo() - bar() - baz(); }

gcc -fPIC -shared -o foo.so foo_v3.c -Wl,--version-script=foo_v3.lds
gcc -w main_v3.c ./foo.so -o main_v3

./main_v3; echo $?
6
```

Now let's run `main_v3` against `foo.so.v2`:

```
cp foo.so.v2 foo.so

./main_v3
./main_v3: ./foo.so: version `FOO_v3' not found (required by ./main_v3)
```

This time, the failure happens at load time. QED.

Comment: Thank you! FYI a colleague of mine also proposed to use the `-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now` linker options, which would require all the symbols to be resolved immediately instead of lazily.

Comment: @MathieuBorderé Oh, right: if you control the link command line of the main executable, `-Wl,-z,now` would also achieve load-time failure (but at possibly significant cost to startup time).